# Return exit from a function - is this possible

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is it possible to return an Exit from a function?

So that I can exit the Page_Load function using the function MyExit

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    MyExit()   'Exit

End Sub

Private Function MyExit() As Exit

    Return Exit 

End Function
```

Comment: What's an `Exit`?

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to stop de loading and close the Form again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can set a flag like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load()
    Dim bExit as Boolean = MyExit()
    If bExit then Exit
End Sub

Private Function MyExit() As Boolean
    Dim bOk as Boolean

    '[...] 

    Return bOk
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Private Sub MyExit()

    End

End Sub
```

Comment: Please, for the love of whatever’s holy, **never** use `End`. There simply is no reason ever to decapitate your program like that. If you need `End` to exit your program easily then your code design is bad.

Comment: I agree with you. However, the question itself is... Well, I enjoyed a lot typing the answer above.